# Generic based member names

Tags: c#, generics

Is it possible in C# to use some sort of pre-processor (or anything) like in C++ to be able to use a type name or a generic type as an identifier within the code?

```
public abstract class PropSC<T1, T2, T3>
{
    public T1 T1 { get; set; }
    public T2 T2 { get; set; }
    public T3 T3 { get; set; }
}
```

So i can later use

```
public class SomeClass : PropSC<SomeBLL, OtherBLL, OtherClass> {...
```

as a shortcut to writing

```
public SomeBLL SomeBLL { get; set; }
...
```

Is this at all possible in C#?

Comment: no, it's not possible

Comment: You can only compile a code on the fly using `CSharpCodeProvider`. But it is inconvenient to use.

Comment: @Dmitry, I believe the [Roslyn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Roslyn) team would disagree with you.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Roslyn still hasn't been officially released yet.  It's still in beta.

Comment: @Servy, it's definitely being released officially (NuGet package and all), but you're right, that's still a technology preview with some issues left to fix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not possible using generics. Identifiers need to be known at compile time but generic types can be generated at run time (e.g. using [`MakeGenericType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.makegenerictype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).

If you really *need* this, you'd have to use some sort of code generation tool.

Answer (score 0):

While it isn't possible to do exactly as you describe (without the reflector or some other pure source of evil), this does something that's similar to what you've described:

```
public class Property<T1> {
    T1 _t1;
    T1 Get<T1>() {
        return _t1;
    }

    void Set<T1>(T1 t1) {
        _t1 = t1;
    }
}

// C# doesn't have variadic generics, but you could do something like this
// to get multiple type arguments
public class Property<T1, T2> : Property<T1> {
    T2 _t2;
    T2 Get<T2>() {
        return _t2;
    }

    void Set<T2>(T2 t2) {
        _t2 = t2;
    }
}
public class Property<T1, T2, T3> : Property<T1, T2> {
    T3 _t3;
    T3 Get<T3>() {
        return _t3;
    }

    void Set<T3>(T3 t3) {
        _t3 = t3;
    }
}
public class Property<T1, T2, T3, T4> : Property<T1, T2, T3> {
// ...
```

No, the latter part isn't [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), so you may want to end up merging this approach with some reflection. For completeness sake, here's how you use it:

```
public class SomeClass : Property<Thing1, Thing2, Thing3> { }

SomeClass someClass = new SomeClass();
someClass.Get<Thing1>();
someClass.Get<Thing2>();
someClass.Get<Thing3>();
```